# How do you work with nested types when implementing a container class?

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a `flatten` method on a container object.

The object I'm making is backed by a `List` like so:

```
public class MyContainer<T> {
    
    private List<T> items
    
    public MyContainer() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<T>();
    }
    
    // rest of methods which operate on the list 

}
```

Easy enough. I can use it in my code as follows:

```
MyContainer<String> stringContainer = new MyContainer<String>();
```

or

```
MyContainer<Integer> intContainer = new MyContainer<Integer>();
```

Which for these kinds of uses, it's easy to implement generic functions.

```
public T get(int i) {
    return this.items.get(i);
}
```

However, you can also 'nest' the objects and types during construction.

```
MyContainer<List<String>> listOfLists = new MyContainer<List<String>>();
```

Now, from an implementation perspective, how do I operate on nested structures like this?

From the compiler's stand point, all that's in the generic class is a `List` of type `T` If I try to fake it and access the list as though it contained a list, the compiler, as expected, complains.

```
public List<T> flatten() {
    for (List<T> nestedSeq : this.items) 
         // nope
}
```

Is there a way to deal with Lists of lists? Can I implement the `flatten` method on my class, or will it need to just be a convenience function on some helper class?

#### EDIT:

To clarify `flatten`, it would flatten out the list of lists in one single list which is then returned as a `MyContainer`

This is the desired functionality.

```
MyContainer<List<String>> myListOfLists = new MyContainer(
    Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"), 
    Arrays.asList("four", "five", "six")
    );


MyContainer<String> flattenedList = myListOfLists.flatten() 

// flattedList contains: ["One", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
```

Comment: You should only flat your own `List`. Don't mind about flattening the possible collection that may be stored inside your `List`.

Comment: If you want to add special functionality for the object of an input list that happen to, themselves, to be a list you could use "instanceof" to see if the "T" type is, itself, a list.  I am not sure why you are trying to do this, however.  What is the purpose behind the code you are trying to run?

Comment: What does `flatten` return?  If there were a `Flattenable` interface what would it look like?

Comment: You haven't said anywhere what the flatten method should take as argument, do, and return. Show us its signature and its javadoc.

Comment: **ignore suggestions to use `instanceof` there is almost always a better solution, and when there isn't you will know it!**

Comment: Upvoted just because i didn't see a motivation to let it downvoted, its a good question

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make much sense: your container class accepts any kind of objects, including objects for which a `flatten()` method can't be used: calling `flatten()` on a `MyContainer<String>` doesn't make sense, unless flattening a MyContainer returns the container itself.

Since the container doesn't know anything about the type of objects it contains, the job of transforming the elements to a list of elements should be left to an external component. For example:

```
/**
 * Transforms each T in this container to an Iterator<K> using the given mapper,
 * and returns a container containing all the elements of all the returned iterators,
 * in sequence.
 */
public <R> MyContainer<R> flatten(Function<? super T, Iterator<? extends R>> mapper)
```

(I chose Iterator, but you could prefer List or Stream, for example)

This is basically what the [`Stream.flatMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) method does, BTW.